# Google Tag Manager content experiment variable not available

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, ab-testing, mobile-analytics

I have setup a content experiment and associated the same with a goal in analytics,I have also added enabling rule for the experiment by linking it to one of the triggers.
Now when I try to access the variable in my iOS app from container, it returns empty description for the same even after the linked trigger was fired. Please suggest what am I missing.

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Have you added Value collection for your content experiment variable ? If yes than you need to remove that as due to some reason container doesn't carry the experiment variation if value collection is present.

Comment: do you mean if I added any data in the variations fields? Yes I added data there. But if I remove it, how can I tell in which variation a user should be in-app?